# Generating TCP traffic in Ubuntu

Tags: tcp, traffic

I want to generate TCP traffic in Ubuntu between two hosts.

I also would like to measure the average RTT in Wireshark.

What is the command in Ubuntu for generating TCP traffic?

First , I used This Command: xterm H1 H2, Then , What Command can I Use in H1? and What Command Can I Use In H2? For Example I Send TCP Traffic From H1 To H2. is there anyone can explain more For Me?

Comment: Welcome to Unix and Linux. A `ping` command is the easiest way to measure the RTT between two endpoints, and you do not even need `wireshark`. I advise taking some time aside to write future questions.

Comment: so thanks my friend i'm not professional , can you give me an example?

Comment: `ping` is not TCP, so does not answer OP's question @RuiFRibeiro

Comment: @ntwrkguru The word "also" might mean something there. The question is also poor, it is difficult to infer what exactly the OP wants hence 5 people VTCing it. I usually prefer to save my energy and time for questions that can have better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `netcat` (`nc`) for that.

For example:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=1 | nc 192.168.108.100 9000
```

will send 1 mebibyte of pseudorandom data to the host with the IP `192.168.108.100` at port `9000`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, First , I used This Command: xterm H1 H2, Then , What Command can I Use in H1? and What Command Can I Use In H2?  For Example I Send TCP Traffic From H1 To H2. can You example more For Me?

Comment: It is exactly command. If your computer is not H1, you can connect to H1 (via ssh, for example) and run it. `192.168.108.100` is H2 in my example.